# Can't concatenate x codes (\x) - PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking to use unpack().

This works:

```
$srbytes = "\x80\x3e\x00\x00";

$array1 = unpack("v",$srbytes);
```

This does not:

```
$num1 = "80"

$srbytes = "\x".$num1."\x3e\x00\x00";

$array1 = unpack("v",$srbytes);
```

or

```
$srbytes = "\x"."80\x3e\x00\x00"; 
$array1 = unpack("v",$srbytes);
```

Printing this with echo shows ASCII chars with the first full string but, the concatenated ones shows text until it passes where it was concatenated.

Comparing a full string against a concatenated ones shows false, even though they should be the same?

what is actually happening when I'm trying to concatenate

Comment: Don't use `echo` for debugging variables. That's what [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var-dump) is for. For example, `var_dump()` would have given you more useful information as to why those two strings aren't equal by comparison, because you'd see one string is longer than the other, and definitely doesn't give you what you expect.

Comment: Your totally right. That extra bit of info would of helped a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

The character expansion won't work, because at the point that you do `"\x" . "80"` PHP already has two string *literals*. It can't be expected to figure that meant anything else *but* this.

Instead of trying to concatenate a hexadecimal value for expansion, just concatenate the actual character, by converting the hexadecimal value to a base10 integer, and passing it to [`chr()`](http://php.net/chr), which converts it to an actual byte.

```
$str = "";
$num1 = "80";
$str .= chr(base_convert($num1, 16, 10));
var_dump($str);
```

Gives you

```
string(1) "�"
```

When you actually look at the value of `$srbytes` in your example where you define it as a string literal `"\x80\x3e\x00\x00"`, what you get is `var_dump("\x80\x3e\x00\x00")` giving you `string(4) "�>"`, because PHP [double quoted strings offer additional character expansion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) such as expanding on escaped hexadecimal values into bytes. However, `var_dump("\x"."80\x3e\x00\x00")` just gives you `string(7) "\x80>"`, which is because the value `"\x"` by itself is just a literal `"\x"` as a string. So they aren't the same values, no.

Comment: This works perfectly. Great explanation I have a lot of studying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the 'literal' string use single quotes. Your issue is with escaped character sequences inside double quotes being evaluated. Example:

```
$srbytes = '\x'.'80\x3e\x00\x00'; 
echo $srbytes;
// \x80\x3e\x00\x00
var_dump($srbytes);
// string(16) "\x80\x3e\x00\x00" 

$srbytes = "\x"."80\x3e\x00\x00"; 
echo $srbytes;
// \x80>
var_dump($srbytes);
//string(7) "\x80>"
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Yea, `echo` isn't going to show you null bytes. `echo` is a pretty bad tool to use for debugging any output, really. Much better to rely on `var_dump()`, because at least it gives you printable and meaningful representation of output that `echo`/`print`/`print_r` simply cannot. Such as length of string, telling when a value is `false` or `null`, etc...

Comment: Definitely not the same result. `string(7) "\x80>"` is giving you information that `echo` is not when all it tells you is `\x80>`, you might think the string just consists of 5 characters. Clearly that isn't the case.

Comment: Ok point taken. Aside from how I chose to debug the string, would you say my answer is incorrect?

Comment: Not saying it's incorrect, no. This was more of a roll-up comment.