# How to calculate CRC-CCITT (XModem) in PHP for HEX input data?

Tags: php, hex, crc, crc16

Below code is from [crc32 function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php#106672) reference in PHP website for CRC16-CCITT calculation. This works for ASCII input data. How can I make it work for HEX input data? What do I need to change? Thank you for your help.

```
    // CRC16-CCITT validator
$crc_table = array(
    0x0,  0x1021,  0x2042,  0x3063,  0x4084,  0x50a5,  0x60c6,  0x70e7,
        0x8108,  0x9129,  0xa14a,  0xb16b,  0xc18c,  0xd1ad,  0xe1ce,  0xf1ef,
        0x1231,  0x210,  0x3273,  0x2252,  0x52b5,  0x4294,  0x72f7,  0x62d6,
        0x9339,  0x8318,  0xb37b,  0xa35a,  0xd3bd,  0xc39c,  0xf3ff,  0xe3de,
        0x2462,  0x3443,  0x420,  0x1401,  0x64e6,  0x74c7,  0x44a4,  0x5485,
        0xa56a,  0xb54b,  0x8528,  0x9509,  0xe5ee,  0xf5cf,  0xc5ac,  0xd58d,
        0x3653,  0x2672,  0x1611,  0x630,  0x76d7,  0x66f6,  0x5695,  0x46b4,
        0xb75b,  0xa77a,  0x9719,  0x8738,  0xf7df,  0xe7fe,  0xd79d,  0xc7bc,
        0x48c4,  0x58e5,  0x6886,  0x78a7,  0x840,  0x1861,  0x2802,  0x3823,
        0xc9cc,  0xd9ed,  0xe98e,  0xf9af,  0x8948,  0x9969,  0xa90a,  0xb92b,
        0x5af5,  0x4ad4,  0x7ab7,  0x6a96,  0x1a71,  0xa50,  0x3a33,  0x2a12,
        0xdbfd,  0xcbdc,  0xfbbf,  0xeb9e,  0x9b79,  0x8b58,  0xbb3b,  0xab1a,
        0x6ca6,  0x7c87,  0x4ce4,  0x5cc5,  0x2c22,  0x3c03,  0xc60,  0x1c41,
        0xedae,  0xfd8f,  0xcdec,  0xddcd,  0xad2a,  0xbd0b,  0x8d68,  0x9d49,
        0x7e97,  0x6eb6,  0x5ed5,  0x4ef4,  0x3e13,  0x2e32,  0x1e51,  0xe70,
        0xff9f,  0xefbe,  0xdfdd,  0xcffc,  0xbf1b,  0xaf3a,  0x9f59,  0x8f78,
        0x9188,  0x81a9,  0xb1ca,  0xa1eb,  0xd10c,  0xc12d,  0xf14e,  0xe16f,
        0x1080,  0xa1,  0x30c2,  0x20e3,  0x5004,  0x4025,  0x7046,  0x6067,
        0x83b9,  0x9398,  0xa3fb,  0xb3da,  0xc33d,  0xd31c,  0xe37f,  0xf35e,
        0x2b1,  0x1290,  0x22f3,  0x32d2,  0x4235,  0x5214,  0x6277,  0x7256,
        0xb5ea,  0xa5cb,  0x95a8,  0x8589,  0xf56e,  0xe54f,  0xd52c,  0xc50d,
        0x34e2,  0x24c3,  0x14a0,  0x481,  0x7466,  0x6447,  0x5424,  0x4405,
        0xa7db,  0xb7fa,  0x8799,  0x97b8,  0xe75f,  0xf77e,  0xc71d,  0xd73c,
        0x26d3,  0x36f2,  0x691,  0x16b0,  0x6657,  0x7676,  0x4615,  0x5634,
        0xd94c,  0xc96d,  0xf90e,  0xe92f,  0x99c8,  0x89e9,  0xb98a,  0xa9ab,
        0x5844,  0x4865,  0x7806,  0x6827,  0x18c0,  0x8e1,  0x3882,  0x28a3,
        0xcb7d,  0xdb5c,  0xeb3f,  0xfb1e,  0x8bf9,  0x9bd8,  0xabbb,  0xbb9a,
        0x4a75,  0x5a54,  0x6a37,  0x7a16,  0xaf1,  0x1ad0,  0x2ab3,  0x3a92,
        0xfd2e,  0xed0f,  0xdd6c,  0xcd4d,  0xbdaa,  0xad8b,  0x9de8,  0x8dc9,
        0x7c26,  0x6c07,  0x5c64,  0x4c45,  0x3ca2,  0x2c83,  0x1ce0,  0xcc1,
        0xef1f,  0xff3e,  0xcf5d,  0xdf7c,  0xaf9b,  0xbfba,  0x8fd9,  0x9ff8,
        0x6e17,  0x7e36,  0x4e55,  0x5e74,  0x2e93,  0x3eb2,  0xed1,  0x1ef0);

    $test = chr(0xC6).chr(0xCE).chr(0xA2).chr(0x03); // CRC16-CCITT = 0xE2B4
    genCRC ($test);
      
function genCRC (&$ptr)
{
    $crc = 0x0000;
    $crc_table = $GLOBALS['crc_table'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($ptr); $i++)
        $crc =  $crc_table[(($crc>>8) ^ ord($ptr[$i]))] ^ (($crc<<8) & 0x00FFFF);
    return $crc;
}
```

For eg. If I provide

```
$test = "7f0100"; //ASCII
```

The function gives DE2E. Expected result is C708 treating 7f0100 as HEX input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to first convert the hexadecimal string into a string of bytes with `hexdec` and `chr` on each pair of hexadecimal digits, and concatenating those into a string.

For your example, you can provide the string of three bytes directly as `"\x7f\x01\x00"`.

Comment: Hi @Mark thank you for helping me. I defined a function function strtohex($string){$string = str_split($string, 2); return "\x".implode('\x',$string);}. For 7f0100 this function returns \x7f\x01\x00. When I directly call genCRC("\x7f\x01\x00"); it gives me C708 but when I call genCRC (strtohex("7f0100")) it gives me CAF6. Am I missing something?

Comment: I found why it's happening, re: comment here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475279/cant-concatenate-x-codes-x-php#comment66270381_39475279.

Comment: Your "strtohex" does no such thing. It simply inserts backslashes and x's into the string. So you turn six characters into 12 characters, instead of into three bytes. Do what I said. Use `hexdec` and `chr`.

Comment: Thank you. This helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382760/php-create-a-valid-byte-string.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mark Adler suggested here's the function to convert hex data to bytes string:

```
function hexToStr($hex){
    $string='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2){
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;
}
```